# android "android.intent.action.SEND" pass it in already running activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I write app for integrate linux PC and android. I want to send link from phone to PC. I have simple example to do this, but this example start new activity. I need receive action.SEND in already running activity or data from this intent in already created class. How O can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find exit. I used Observer.I created the Observable class, added the model to the observer, and from the activity (not the main one), I called the Observable method, to which I passed the data, and already notifyObservers (Text). So everything works fine.